# Django & python when I run ' makemigrations'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am a junior in python and I want to make a webservice using django , i wrote my model.py and it seems like there is a problem in my classes but I can't fix it.
I don't know if the error is in ' the related name ' or in the models

the error message =after runing the commande ' makemigrations' is :

```
ERRORS:
PSTL.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.

    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'User.groups'.

PSTL.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.
auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'User.groups'.
auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.
```

and my model.py is :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser #BASE
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from datetime import *

class User(AbstractUser):

    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    type = models.TextField(max_length=20)
    ########################################################
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.username


class CompteCandidat(User):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    prenom=models.TextField(max_length=50)
    sexe = models.TextField(max_length=10)
    datecr = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    cv = models.OneToOneField('CV',related_name="CompteCcv")
    demande=models.OneToOneField('Adresse',related_name="CompteCdemande")

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2

        return self.name



class CompteRE(User):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    accronime = models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    fondateur = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    dateF= models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True,blank=False,null=False)
    site= models.TextField(max_length=20)
    fax=models.TextField(max_length=20)
    activite=models.TextField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class CompteRF(User):
    name = models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    accronime = models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    site= models.TextField(max_length=20)
    fax=models.TextField(max_length=20)
    #######################################################
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class CV(models.Model):
    numtel = models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
    datecv= models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True,blank=False,null=False)
    pathcv = models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    compteCand = models.OneToOneField('CompteCandidat',related_name="cvss")
    competence=models.ManyToManyField('Competence',related_name="cvss",blank=True)
    #######################################################
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Competence(models.Model):
    cv=models.ManyToManyField('CV',related_name="cv",blank=True)
    #######################################################
    def CVs(self):
        return self.cv.all()


class Diplome(Competence):
    type=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    domaine=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    specialite=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    annee=models.DateTimeField(auto_now = False,blank=False,null=False)
    #######################################################


class CompetenceTech(Competence):
    domaine=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    valeur=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    #######################################################


class CompetenceLang(Competence):
    langue=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    niveau=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    #######################################################


class Adresse(models.Model):
    numV=models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
    complementdest=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    complementadr=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    commune=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    codeP=models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
    pays=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    compteCand=models.OneToOneField('CompteCandidat',related_name="ad")



class Demande(models.Model):
    nom=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    prenom=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    pathcv=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)


class Stage(models.Model):
    typeposte=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    diplome=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    niveau=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    duree=models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
    commentaire=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)

class FicheFormation(models.Model):
    intitule=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    duree=models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
    objective=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    nbrUE=models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
    niveau=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    prix=models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
    unitef=models.ManyToManyField('FicheFormation',related_name="fichef",blank=True)

class UniteFormation(models.Model):
    nomUe=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    accronime=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    commentaire=models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
```

Comment: There is already a built-in class called User, if you want to add extra fields to it, it's better to create a one-to-one relation as described here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: Did you forget to set the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting to your custom user model? You need to set it to `'PSTL.User'` so that Django knows to use your User model, and not the default one.